# Hiding email address associated with Apple ID when using iMessage

Tags: iphone

When sending an iMessage to a recipient, they see the email address associated with the sender's Apple ID. As a sender, is it possible to hide the email from the receiver, instead having the parties refer to each other using only a phone number?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which ID (phone number or Apple ID email) to use when starting a new iMessage conversation.

To configure, on your iPhone, go to Settings app → Messages → Send & Receive and under **Start New Conversations From**, select the phone number instead of email addresses associated with your Apple ID.

[image]